# Eclipse always hangs for a few seconds when adding/removing breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I am facing this problem for some time now: No matter if my tomcat server is started or not, my eclipse always takes some time when i want to add/remove or de/activate breakpoints. Apart from that eclipse is as fast as i would expect it to be.

I guess my system should not be the problem:
Windows 10,
20gb RAM,
Java 8 Upd 151,
Eclipse Oxygen (Xms2048m, Xmx4096m),
Tomcat 8.0.xx (Xms1024m, Xmx2048m),

I currently have 7 web projects in my eclipse workspace, each deployed to its own tomcat. It does not seem to matter if i close all of them despite my current project, the problem still occurs. I have had this problem on neon as well as now on oxygen. It also does not seem to matter how many breakpoints i have set, the problem occurs even when setting the first breakpoint.

I was doing some research to this problem, but did not find any useful hint to this problem. Does anyone know how to tweak eclipse properly?

Comment: Open the "error view" and look for entries named "UI freeze". They should contain stack traces which _sometimes_ indicate what the problem is or if it is caused by some plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902230/eclipse-always-hangs-for-a-few-seconds-when-adding-removing-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Always i face this Problem, i remove all breakpoints.
Run -> Remove All Breakpoints -> Restart eclipse
(Third item from screenshot bottom)

[image]